# passenger don't run on app path 'Could not find passenger'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

running passenger on the app path (e.g /home/my_app/rails) as such:

```
rvmsudo passenger start
```

raising error

> dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find passenger ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by conflict with the project gems. You should run the command outside of the app, giving passenger the app path to handle.

```
cd ~
rvmsudo passenger start my_app/rails
```